# Add xy data to Arcgis cannot specify x and y fields?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, excel

I have imported the excel data files into Arcgis by add XY data dialog box. It ran into problem that the table selected to specify the field shows only first box where they would usually display a column header like "Longitude" (see picture below).

Comment: Where is the picture? Use the edit button to include it in the question (don't post it as an answer).

Answer (score 1):

Format both fields as "Number" in Excel then retry it.

Comment: The excel data contains id,x and y in first row and numeric values in other cells.

Comment: should be two different column X and Y representing latitude and longitude, this field should be stored as number (even if they have just numeric value). Open excel file select both column and format them as number.

Comment: than when you will chose the fields, arcgis will appear these fields